# Python{RobotFramework} Function returns 3 values but on collecting them in 3 variables getting "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Tags: python-2.7, function, return-value, robotframework

This is my function:

```
def postTenant(self, data):


    rt = True
    result = 'No Error!'
    ews_content = {}
    Authorization_header = ''
    for i in range(0, 5):
        try:
            # pushchannel_link = '/' + service + '/pushchannels'
            link = "https://sereverapi/servername/abc"
            h = httplib2.Http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True, timeout=60)
            resp, content = h.request(link,
                                      'POST',
                                      data,
                                      headers={'content-type': 'application/json'})
            print resp
            print content
            # print type(content)
            print resp.status
            if resp.status == 200:
                rt = True
                result = 'No Error!'
                print "Tenant created"
                ews_content = json.loads(content)
                final = (((ews_content["connectinfo"])["authentication"])["basic"])
                auth = ('{}:{}'.format(str(final["user"]), str(final["password"])))
                auth_encoded = auth.encode('base64')
                Authorization_header = 'Basic {}'.format(auth_encoded)
                print 'Auth Header generated'
                print Authorization_header
                print type(Authorization_header)
            elif resp.status == 409:
                print "Conflict received"
                rt = True
                result = 'Conflict!'
            else:
                rt = False
        except Exception, strerror:
            print 'Exception occurs:' + str(strerror)
            rt = False
            result = str(strerror)
        finally:
            print 'Now in finally block'
            # GenAuthHeader(content)
            if rt:
                break;
    return rt, result, Authorization_header
```

[Robot framework file to run the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9meYf.png)

The error is:

> Value Error, too many values to unpack
>
> where the values of my return variables as generated by function is :
>   rt = True; result = 'No Error!' and  Authorization_header = 'Basic
>   cnVuYXVzZrttttdlajldjf123UVVBRUVdPQlZYQk86JkhiQiVYdVExJktmbFJiQmlSJUB0dWNk
>   NmWER231RGw='

Comment: Please don't link to a picture of the code that runs the keyword. Take the time to copy and paste the code into the question.

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Have you tried storing the result in a single variable and then examining the variable to make sure it contains what you assume it contains? Even though your function returns three values, perhaps the keyword that calls the function returns only one.

Comment: @BryanOakley... The function returns 3 values and the keyword (the name of the method itself) calling the function also should makes it return 3 values. The screenshot is of the file(in my robot framework) which calls the class and the method i am trying to run.

I cant store the return values in a single var as i need different specific values which my function is giving me.

Plz tell if there is anything else you need from myside to understand the error here

I have tried

Comment: When you say _" also should makes it return 3 values"_, have you verified that what it _should_ do is what it is _actually_ doing?  Also, I'm not asking you to permanently store the values in a single variable, I'm asking that you do it temporarily so that you can see what is being returned. Finally, I know what the screenshot is. Nobody on stackoverflow likes screenshots of code. Take the time to post actual code so that we can copy and paste it to reproduce the error.

Comment: What do you mean.I am declaring these 3 vars within the function itself and assigning them values based on a certain behaviour.I am just returning these variables.whic is totally fine.

Problem is that when i call the function here..and trying the store the 3 returned values in 3 diffrent variable containers
{result} {data} {data1}..its throwing me the error 

${result}    ${data}    ${data1}    Execute    restapi    postTenant
     ...   ${data}

Also,made sure that all the return values are strings so that the collecting variables can collect them without any issue of datatype.

Comment: The keyword you are calling is `execute`. Are you absolutely certain that that keyword returns three values? Apparently it's not. The question you need to answer isn't "what does postTenant return?", but "what does `execute  restapi` return?" You need to be certain that it is returning the result of the function rather than something else (for example, some sort of 'result' object that includes the http status as well as the data).

Comment: What is the variable type of `Authorization_header`?

Comment: @BrandonOlson its ‘str’

Comment: Okay, and what is its value that it prints out to the screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your integration of Robot Framework and Python code. Fundamentally, Robot Framework allows you to call Python-style evaluations of expressions (and only expressions) with `Evaluate`, located in the BuiltIn library. If `Execute` exists in your test setup, it's probably a custom keyword, not a normal one since I can't find documentation for it anywhere to see what it returns. The closest I found in the base Robot Framework documentation (not even listed as a keyword) is `Execute Command`, but that's probably not what you're looking for.

The way Robot Framework allows you to use Python code like you're trying to do is by creating a new Python-based library. The documentation for that exists in other places on this site (several times it was put there by me, so you can probably look through my answered questions for a short[er] list of places to go). If you re-write your Python code into a library format, then you can call your keyword as you would any other keyword and, assuming you set it up correctly, you shouldn't have any further problems with returning three variables.

Robot Framework does not (to the best of my knowledge, please correct me if you know better) allow you to run Python code in any other way than the two I've put here.

EDIT: I was corrected by someone who knows better, but I'm not familiar with REST calls. However, I do know that creating this as a Library should work.

Comment: The third way is via a REST call, which seems to be what the OP is doing. The problem seems to be -- as you've pointed out -- that `execute  restapi` isn't returning exactly what `postTenant` returns.